# AHK - if difference is greater than 10

Tags: autohotkey

An image file is auto-generated every 10 seconds, and the aim of my script is to prompt when there is a failure in auto generation of image. I have included MsgBox for illustration Seems like there is an error in how I have structured to check the difference, can somebody please help?

```
`::
FileGetTime, Updated, C:\auto-generated-image.png, M
FormatTime, Updated, %Updated%, HHmmss
MsgBox, Time Now: %A_Hour%%A_Min%%A_Sec% ; for illustration
MsgBox, File Updated: %Updated% ; for illustration
**if (%A_Hour%%A_Min%%A_Sec% - Updated) > 10**
MsgBox, Image Auto Generation Has Failed! 
return
```

Comment: Figured it out,

Comment: ````
`::
FileGetTime, Updated, C:\auto-generated-image.png, M
var1 := A_now
var2 := Updated
var3 := A_now - Updated
if (var3 > 10)
MsgBox, Image Auto Generation Has Failed!
return
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
::
FileGetTime, Updated, C:\auto-generated-image.png, M
var1 := A_now
var2 := Updated
var3 := A_now - Updated
if (var3 > 10)
MsgBox, Image Auto Generation Has Failed
return
```

If there is alternate way of doing this, please comment, thanks